# use of cookies in javascript

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
<div id="cookierr" class="cook"><a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff">This site uses cookies Learn more</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I understand Hide this message <img src="<?=$img_loc?>abc.png" style="margin-bottom:-4px; cursor:pointer;" class="cross"/></div>

        <script>
         $(function() {
          $(".cross").on("click", function(){
            $(".cook").remove();
            $.cookie('cook', '1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
          });
        });
        </script>
```

In my site this is a div when u click on the abc.png ie cross button . the whole div is removed and i am saving it a cookie so that the user never see this again . but the cookie part is showing me the error . am i doing something wrong plz help me

Comment: did you add the cookie plugin to your site

Comment: nope but how to add the cookie plugin because I was just following jibjab.com

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js"></script>`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'cookie' (index):37
(anonymous function) (index):37
p.event.dispatch jquery.js:2
g.handle.h

Comment: Try embedding the cookie script suggested by @ArunPJohny

Comment: Download the cookie script from http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ and add it to your javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it is clear that the cookie plugin is not added to the page.

Add it using [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/)

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js"‌​></script>
```

Or download the [script file](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) from the [plugin site](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and include it in your page

Also you may have to add code to remove it on page load if the cookie is already set

```
$(function () {
    var cookie = $.cookie('cook');
    if (cookie) {
        $(".cook").remove();
    } else {
        $(".cross").on("click", function () {
            $(".cook").remove();
            $.cookie('cook', '1', {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LCF4e/)

Comment: In other words: jQuery itself does not provide cookie support.

Comment: @PHP_USER1 did you check the fiddle

Comment: after i click on the cross button , div is remove but wen i refreshes the page . it again show me the div

Comment: @PHP_USER1 in your page or in the fiddle